# Using aluminium electrolytic capacitors in RC filter

Tags: capacitor, filter, low-pass, electrolytic-capacitor

I have a RC filter on which I need to increase the capacitance. I have one 47uF ceramic capacitor and 2 47uF aluminum electrolytic ones at home. Can I use these in parallel in the RC circuit?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: For what kind of signal? And what arrangement of filter?

Comment: PWM going from 0 to 5V.

Comment: How much current are these capacitors being asked to handle? Is this circuit part of the power stage of some kind of amplifier or power supply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a low-pass filter for PWM where the voltage is always the same polarity yes, you can use multiple electrolytics:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUcxDF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You might also consider a "Pi" RC circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGQjiy.png)</sup>

For lower losses it is better to replace the resistor with a suitable inductor to make an LC circuit.